# Mesos master slave communication

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

How do master and slave communicate is Mesos. Does the master run a webserver? Is it using HTTP or TCP/IP requests ?

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4):

Master and worker (aka slave) exchange protobuf messages packed in HTTP/1.1. Master has a tiny built-in webserver that processes messages from workers and requests coming via HTTP endpoints. If you want to learn more, you can start with looking at `mesos/3rdparty/libprocess/src/encoder.hpp:107`